# Why my free credits in Google cloud are not being consumed when I deploy a VM or buy a domain , does that mean my card is being charged?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google cloud and I am using free credits from google for signup.
But till today not even 1 credit is consumed , I have used Cloud Domains service to buy one domain that costed 860 INR and deployed a VM that said more than 6000 per month , there is no sign of any payment activity in billing center it always says 0 . I am worried because if my card is being used for payments.
thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Billing. Review what you are being charged for and the card transactions. 2) AFAIK, you cannot purchase a domain name using free credits. 3) If you have questions, contact Googe Cloud Billing Support which is free.

Answer (score 5):

By default "promotions" are not displayed when you look at GCP Console - Billing - Reports, which is what you are seeing by default when you click in "Billing". That is why you are seeing $0 as the total cost for the report.

On the right side of the "Billings - Report", in the filters, you will find the option to deselect "Promotions and others". After deselecting such an option you will see the detailed cost of the services you are using for your GCP account.

To see how many credits you still own, you have to go to "Billings - Overview" and click on "Credit details" card.

Obviously buying a domain is not included in the free tier or with the credits, how are you going to return the domain name after the 90-day trial expires?.

For the rest of the services, you will find what is included in the free tier [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier), and in the "Credit details" section you will find where that credits can be used.

Comment: This is a good answer. Google has created a number of short videos on Google Cloud Billing. I organized Google's videos into a training videolab. https://videolabs.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/

Answer (score -1):

I managed to buy 10 Cloud Domains with my free credit with one of my google accounts, I was able to transfer them to Google Domains. I have tried this again on a new account but it says quota limit reached. Strange.